# Rails rendering instance variable from application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render, instance-variables, partials

I am following the Agile Web Development with Rails 4 book and I'm a bit confused on a part about rendering.  The simple version of the question is... within the application.html.erb file there it says

```
render @cart
```

This is confusing because I thought that there needed to be a controller associated with that view in order to know which partial and @cart variable to use.  Is it simply by naming convention that this line looks for a partial like _cart.html.erb? And in that case does it not actually know what @cart is until it renders that partial?

Some clarification would be lovely.  Thanks!

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html. Great resource for anyone struggling to find succinct information regarding the topic. Also explains other concepts related to passing instance variables as partials.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a shorthand syntax. [From the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html):

Every partial also has a local variable with the same name as the partial (minus the underscore). You can pass an object in to this local variable via the :object option:

```
<%= render partial: "customer", object: @new_customer %>
```

Within the customer partial, the customer variable will refer to @new_customer from the parent view.

If you have an instance of a model to render into a partial, you can use a shorthand syntax:

```
<%= render @customer %>
```

Assuming that the @customer instance variable contains an instance of the Customer model, this will use _customer.html.erb to render it and will pass the local variable customer into the partial which will refer to the @customer instance variable in the parent view.

Comment: so if there is a :customer in the model, you can user render @customer and it doesn't pass any information and just looks for a partial named _customer?

Comment: it looks for the partial named _customer and also passes the instance variable named `@customer` which is defined from the parent view. In the first example in my answer, they are showing how to pass in a different instance variable, `@new_customer`, but if you have an instance variable with the same name, you can use the shorthand.

Comment: I think application.html.erb is the parent view. With render `@cart` in the application.html.erb, the variable `@cart` should change depending on what view is being accessed.  So for the index action, @cart would be whatever is defined in the index controller. I'm sort of guessing here, though :)