# nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Getting an error trying to run my Rails app.  I think it might be a data issue based on a similar error I researched in Stack Overflow. Below is the output from the Command Line:

```
ActionView::Template::Error ('nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.):
2: <% provide(:blog_active, 'active') %>
3:
4: <div class="row">
5:   <%= render @posts %>
6: </div>

app/views/blog/posts/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_blog_posts_index_html_erb__817338750_58788108'
```

Comment: can you add `<% p ['@posts is', @posts] %>` and watch the spew on your console to see if it's nil?

Comment: Philip, thanks for your suggestion; where exactly to I insert this code?  Again, thanks.

Comment: just above your `<div class="row">`

Comment: Cool thanks...trying it now.

Comment: Got the following:  ActionView::Template::Error ('nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.):
    2: <% provide(:blog_active, 'active') %>
    3: <% p ['@posts is', @posts] %>
    4: <div class="row">
    5:   <%= render @posts %>
    6: </div>

app/views/blog/posts/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_blog_posts_index_html_erb__299498262_61543404'

Comment: But what did your console say just before it spewed the error? You are looking for the output of the `p` call.

Comment: He's what is above: 
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-25 12:33:51 -0700
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by Blog::PostsController#index as HTML
  Rendering blog/posts/index.html.erb within layouts/blog
["@posts is", nil]
  Rendered blog/posts/index.html.erb within layouts/blog (328.3ms)
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1826ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: There it is: `["@posts is", nil]`. look at your controller code (or post it) to see what sets `@posts`, and if it's screwing up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a discrepancy with the name of your partial. Are you sure it is _posts.html.erb and not _post.html.erb?

I just found this Stack Overflow question that's related: 
[Rails rendering instance variable from application.html.erb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747795/rails-rendering-instance-variable-from-application-html-erb)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, it is labeled _post.html.erb...re-running it now...fingers-crossed.

Comment: Same error after changing the file name to _posts.html.erb.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: Ashwin thanks for asking.  Not yet.  I just started from the beginning and can't get the image in my app to display.  Working on that now.  I will post my plea for assistance.

Comment: Sure. Please do post the code and let me have a look at it. Please send the link of your new question here :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. And my problem was with **@posts** variable in my **PostsController #index**. I made a mistake writing the **@posts** variable.
And when I fixed the **@posts** value, the problem was gone.